# Is the application of the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell Theorem really necessary?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, residuals, instrumental-variables

Suppose I have a model 
\begin{eqnarray}
y = X_1 \beta + X_2 \gamma + \epsilon \\
X = Z \Pi + V
\end{eqnarray}
where $X_1$ is endogenous, Z are instruments, $X_2$ are exogenous. If I however include all my exogenous regressors in some joint matrix $[X_1,X_2]$ and outfit my instruments with X_2 as well (so they instrument for themselves). Does that simplify expressions used in obtaining this estimator (LIML) with X now $(X_1,X_2)$
\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{\beta}_{LIML} = (X'(I - \lambda M_Z) X)^{-1} (X'(I-\lambda M_Z) Y),
\end{eqnarray}
where $\lambda$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $W_1 W^{-1}$ where $W_1 = (Y,X_1)'M_{X_2}(Y,X_1)$ and $W= (Y,X_1)'M_Z (Y,X_1)$.

My guess is that if you replace $X_1$ with $(X_1, X_2)$ and take Z = $(Z_1,X_2)$, so that Z is augmented by the included exogenous regressors, we should see some simplification?

Is it correct to then write

$$W_1 = (Y,X_1,X_2)'(Y,X_1,X_2)$$

$$W= (Y,X_1,X_2)'M_Z (Y,X_1,X_2)$$, where Z in this last equation is the augmented instrument matrix?

Thanks so much!

(Source [here](http://are.berkeley.edu/courses/ARE213/spring2006/lect18_06apr10.pdf) pages 4 and 5)